# Installation of Qt 5.6.1 MSVC 2015 Update 3

Tags: qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have encountered the following problem during a routine Qt 5 installation combined with Visual Studio 2015:

I did these steps:

1. Installed visual studio 2015 enterprise
2. Updated it to Update 3 (recent)
3. Installed X64 Debuggers And Tools-x64_en-us + 32bit
4. Installed Qt 5.6
5. I inspected the automatic detection of compiler, debuggers and the build environment comparing it to another machine, and all look OK.
6. Created new test projects using empty console application, Qt quick.

All fail during compilation step, with exactly 20 errors:

[20 compile errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zhn0.jpg)

I noted that the errors appears in code files of VC++ include path
for example in the code file xtr1common (first error in the picture).
I installed and used Qt with MSVC including MSVC Update 2 many times before but not with Update 3.  What went wrong?  How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Same errors when compiling a simple hello world project with no Qt?

Comment: I found a silly solution and I need a better one: here is what I did; I edited single entry in the project include path to an include folder that is copied from another machine with Visual Studio 2015 update 2. ->> I swapped the path of this folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE with another one taken from the VS2015 update 2 in the project build environment (under build settings). Therefore I think Microsoft broke something in the update 3.

Comment: Luckily I have another machine with MSVC 2015 update 2 and I did what you said and IT WORKS.

Comment: Nice workaround using the old standard library header files! As for the 20 compile errors, are you able to double-click on the errors and go to the Visual Studio Output tab to see more detail? After lots of "instantiated from" messages, each error should show the top-level line of source code that is being compiled when the errors are encountered. I'm curious if they're all from the same top-level line of source code, or from different lines, and what those top-level lines of source code look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to windows updates and remove the visual studio update 3. This will return visual studio to original status including the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE folder.

I hope there is a better answer than this because I needed the visual studio update 3 for other purposes than Qt. But what to do if the Qt 5.6.1 is not compatible with Visual Studio 2015 update 3. If someone have a better answer please hit me.